# C# linq-to-sql, set a database session variable in every session

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

Question:
Is there a way to set a database session variable:

```
declare @app_user varchar(30)='otto'
```

using linq-to-sql in C#, such that the variable is available to triggers in the DB?

Background:
I'm implementing poor-man's journaling using triggers, and I want to pass the application user for inclusion in the journal table:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [Trg_Jrn_Table1] ON [dbo].[Table1]
FOR INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE AS
...
INSERT INTO dbo.[Jrn_Table1] ([jrnDmlType],[jrnUser],<cols>...)
SELECT @dml_type, @app_user, <cols> FROM inserted i WITH (NOLOCK)
```

(I know that I'll need to do a bit with suser_sname to track ad hoc changes, too)

Everything I can find about linq2sql and session variables is focused on C# session variables, and I don't really know where to start.  I was hoping for something like:

```
DataContext dc = createDataContext(cfg);
dc.addSessionData("app_user", "otto");
```

But naturally that doesn't exist :-)

Is a db session variable even possible?  Or maybe something using `:setvar` or `CONTEXT_INFO`?

**Update 4/22/2016:**
I've tried adding c# code in two places, where the DataContext is created and right before an update.  I can see my command being executed in the log, but from within the triggers, the temporary data is unavailable.

1. Setting a session variable:

   ```
   DataContext.ExecuteCommand("declare @app_user varchar(30)={0}", username);
   ```
2. In a temp table

   ```
   DataContext.ExecuteCommand("select {0} usrName into #session_info", username);
   ```
3. Using context_info (see: [link](http://jasondentler.com/blog/2010/01/exploiting-context_info-for-fun-and-audit/))

   ```
   DataContext.ExecuteCommand("declare @Length tinyint;declare @Ctx varbinary(128);select @Length = len({0});select @Ctx = convert(binary(1), @Length) + convert(varbinary(127), {1});set context_info @Ctx", username, username);
   ```

Comment: You may want to do something like a session table instead. Your c# could generate a `Guid` that you can insert into the session table as a session key of sorts. Then you can design your table to have any number of columns that you may need for storing session specific data.

Comment: I think the same problem applies with a session table - when I'm inside the trigger, how can I know which guid to lookup in the session table?  Linq2sql is generating the insert/update/delete statements, and I don't see a way to set a value from within the c# code that the trigger can find.